# How do you decode a string in ternary (or any unusual base)?

Tags: python, radix, ternary

For binary, quaternery, octonery and hex it's clear for me how to convert a stream of them to plain text. Can anybody help me understand how should I do it for ternary, quinary, senary and other bases? ([Here](https://nofile.io/f/6e9PSwZh2cn/ternary.txt)'s a ternary example, a python script would be appreciated) 
So far I've tried:

- Decoding every number to it's binary counterpart, `0->00`, `1->01` and `2->10`
- Creating chunks of 3 characters and map them to English alphabets which didn't work either: `000->a`,`001->b` and so on till `221->z`

Here's my code:

```
from numpy import *
import binascii

base =3
base_data = ''
with open ("./base%s"%base,'r') as b3:
    for line in b3:
        base_data = base_data + line.strip('\r\n')
output = []
all_nums_in_base = range(base)
list_chars = list(base_data)
final = ''
for char in list_chars:
    if char == '0':
        output += ['0']
    elif char == '1':
        output += ['1']
    elif char == '2':
        output += ['1','0']
output = ''.join(output)
n = int('ob'+output,2)
print binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n)
```

and my result is in this format:

```
JMN4,�J�j�T*2VYI�F�%��TjYCL���Y�E�&�
�I��̚dYCL�Z�
�K*�թ��-P��Qie�K"q�jL��5j�Y���K0�C�K2i�f�
```

Comment: Just reverse however it was *encoded*?

Comment: @StefanPochmann but how should I know how it is encoded? I just have a stream of ternary numbers. Should I try to bruteforce different approaches?

Comment: Binary, ternary, etc. are positional numeral systems. They encode numbers, not text. If you're expecting English, you're going to need some additional layer of encoding, and some way to separate the representations of adjacent numbers.

Comment: @Yugi If *you* didn't encode it, then ask the person who did.

Comment: @user2357112 that stream of numbers is the only thing I'm provided with. Is there any approach to find the separation element? or should I just try more ways ?

Comment: It's not particularly hard to convert an e.g. ternary numeric stream to an e.g. binary or hex numeric stream. But to convert that "standard base" stream to text you'd need to what encoding was used. You could probably guess ASCII, UTF-8, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your example data (abbreviated here):

```
> s = '''010020010202011000010200011010011001010202001012...'''
> ''.join(chr(int(s[i:i+6], 3)) for i in range(0, len(s), 6))
=> 'Welcome to base 3!\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...'
```

I guessed that it encodes each character in six ternary digits because your example data's length is a multiple of 6 and 3<sup>6</sup> is the smallest power of 3 larger than or equal to 2<sup>8</sup>.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, could you please describe why did you care about 2^8?

Comment: I assumed they encoded bytes, and that's how many possible values a byte has.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now completely understand. Just solved similar thing for base 5.